# can't install sailfin on eclipse

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I am trying to build a conferencing application with Java under the IDE eclipse Juno. The API I thought that could help me is sailfin. But whenever I try to install it, it doesn't create the sailfin directory he is supposed to. Therefore I cannot proceed and still stuck at that point. I installed the latest version of ant and set up everything according to the tutorial but still it won't work. If anybody has an idea or experience the same difficulties before, it'd be grateful if you could provide me with some insights/ideas on how to get around the situation or maybe suggest another API I could use.

Thanks in advance for all your contributions and time.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented intelligent sip server for the engineering project in 2009 and at that time i also tried to use eclipse to run a sailfinn but can not get success. So i completed project with NETBEANS. It was good with NETBEANS because glassfish is the embedded server and sailfinn depends on glassfish arcihecture. Try Netbeans.